# Bootstrap. How can I get a column filling two rows?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to design a footer with two rows. First one with 4 columns and the second row just one column 3 columns first row width. And the whitespace must be filled for the last column in first row. Check the attached picture to understand the problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrgQr.png

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A modern way to accomplish this would be to create a 4x2 grid using 'CSS Grid', but we'll work with your bootstrap library. From first glance, you have 1 parent `row` with 2 columns. In the left side, you have 3 more columns with 1 full-width column below it. We can then set the height equal to each other by changing the `display` type to `flex`.

```css
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  /*extra styling*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4"><p>text</p></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4"><p>text</p></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4"><p>text</p></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12"><p>text</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's two columns: first one is 9, second on is 3 (wide).
We leave the second column for two row cell. In the first column we create two rows. First one with 3 columns, the second one with one column.
(Click on "full page" when viewing the code snippet, or you can also view it here: https://jsfiddle.net/3g8b2dhx/3/)

```css
.row{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/400x200" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/400x200" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/400x200" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/1200x200" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/400x200" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```